# Caching issue with Aquia development and production environments

Tags: caching, drupal, environment, production

I am having caching issue in my drupal site. My drupal site has about 2000 users and relatively average size of content and I am using Aquia (https://www.acquia.com/). Each time I push content to production from development, it takes a long time for users to see the changes.  The experience is even worse with Internet Explorer.  Any ideas to solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

On `admin/config/development/performance` set `'Expiration of cached pages'` to something decent for your needs, like 1 hour. Also, see if [clearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW1fy.png) the `Varnish` cache helps.

Comment: Many thanks @Alexei and Casper.  I have attempted setting the expiration to 15 mins but not much improvement. I'll try 1 hour to see what if that helps.

Comment: In my case, I use Aquia and Aquia has a separate Varnish server that works for all drupal sites hosted on Aquia.  Therefore, I don't have access to clear Varnish cache.  Any way around this?